# Display all fields underneath pivot table group if group contains value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am looking to display site owner URLs (Row 1) along with the site owner **and** co-owners (Row 2).

I want individual site owners to come into the spreadsheet, view all sites they are listed as an owner as, then be able to view who else is an owner.

Ex. "System Analyst" enters spreadsheet, filters by their name.

*They will receive*

- Row 2

  - Owner 1
  - Owner 2
  - Owner 3 (Them)
  - ...etc
- Row 3

  - Owner 1
  - Owner 2
  - Owner 3 (Them)
  - ...etc

*They will NOT receive*

- Row 1

  - Owner 1
  - Owner 2
  - ...etc

They receive row 2, 3 because they are listed as an owner. They do not receive row 1 because they are NOT listed as an owner. Help would be much appreciated, thank you!

[Pivot Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5DE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered a solution, though not a clean one. Using this post: https://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table

- Use above post to get full length values
- True / False (=Site Link[A2]<>Site Link[A3]), this displays whether the value is the full combined value
- Copy full length values, paste as values in new column ONLY IF the value is the full combined value
- Check if cell above full combined value is blank, if so, copy value from underneath. =IF([@[Full Combined Values Only ]]="",N9, N8)
- Repeat this copying between 3 different columns (I used a quick macro), to copy new values (One row above full value filled), paste to a new column as text, copy to original column (originally with only one full set per group), and repeat.

This is a LOT of words, I don't know a better way to phrase this. If anyone has any ideas of a better way (with less steps), please let me know, I'd be curious. Looking for the full concatenated values in EVERY row, not just one per group.